# core dump are not generated on lxc guest

Tags: coredump, lxc

I set ulimit as unlimited for core files on both host and lxc guest even for root on host, I'm able generate core file on host but not on lxc guest. Is there any configuration in lxc for core file generation?

My host is ubuntu 12.04, lxc guest is centos 5.

Thanks

Comment: I had a similar problem,

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29172874/where-are-core-files-stored-in-a-lxc-container/29172974#29172974

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have any of the apport packages installed (apport apport-gtk apport-kde).
The problem is apport package which redirects core dumps by setting /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern (see man core for more info).
The quick solution might be:
sudo aptitude remove apport apport-gtk apport-kde