# Where are core files stored in a lxc container?

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, lxc

When I am running code on a container  it cores I am not able to locate it on my container(or the core file is not being stored).

1. `ulimit -c` is set to `unlimited`
2. `/proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern` is set to 
   `|/usr/share/apport/apport %p %s %c %P` (what is the meaning of `|`?)

Do I need to make any changes in/to the host system?

Comment: What is the right set up cores on a container?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`|` indicates that a program should handle the core dump. Rather than saving the coredump to a file it will be piped into that programs input. Means if `core_pattern` is set to `|... apport` `apport` will handle the core dumps.

Unfortunately `apport` will create coredumps only for `installed` packages. I would set the pattern to a file name, like this:

```
echo '/tmp/cores/core.%e.%p.%t' > /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern
```

The would give you coredumps like `/tmp/core.program.pid.012345678` where `program` is the program name, `pid` the program's pid plus a timestamp at the end.

Check [`man core`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/core.5.html) for more information (espcecially information about meta chars that can be used in the core pattern.

Comment: I was thinking about what you have suggested, some of the questions are more towards containers than core files like:
1. Should I change the core pattern in my container or my host ubuntu machine?
2. If I need to change it in my container, I am not able to edit the file as root

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot test it at the moment but it would make sense to configure it in the host. Have you tried that?